# Tap-to-focus square visual indicator shows up on iOS4 but not iOS5

Tags: ios5, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an instance of UIImagePickerControler that I have customized to allow me to use my own buttonBar and not Apple's default.

here is the implementation code.

```
- (void)presentCameraPicker
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) 
    {
    photoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    photoPicker.delegate = self;
    photoPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    photoPicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
    photoPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;

    cameraOverlayVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 426, 320, 54);

    [photoPicker.cameraOverlayView addSubview:cameraOverlayVC.view];
    [self presentModalViewController:photoPicker animated:YES];

    }
}
```

I have tested it on both versions, iOS4 (4.3 on a iPodTouch 4th Gen) and iOS5 (5.1 on a iPhone 4S). On the iOS4, when the UIImagePicker is on-screen I can tap on the live view image and I get both the tap-to-focus functionality (and AE) and the default focus square visual indicator, just like in Apple's Camera App. On iOS5 I get the same tap-to-focus functionality, but no visual indicator. I could add a new overlay view to simulate Apple's visual indicator, but on iOS4 I would get two superimposed visual indicators on-screen.

Any ideas or suggestions to solve this issue would be appreciated.